# Question re \everypar, hang paragraphs, Plain TeX

Tags: paragraphs

I'm trying to use `\everypar{\hang\setbox0=\lastbox}` to set a glossary (instead of prepending every entry with `\hang\noindent`). It works fine if everything is in the same font, but if I try to set the headword in a different font the hang paragraphing breaks:

```
{\everypar{\hang\setbox0=\lastbox}
H\&J: Hyphenation and Justification. H\&J rules control how text is typeset into lines of type, how words are broken at line ends and whether the column edges are ragged or straight (justified).

Hairline: Thin printed line, usually 0.25 or 0.5 points thick.

{\it Half-title:} Normally in a hardback book, the first printed page, containing only the title of the book. Can also be used for a similar page appearing later in the prelims. Can also mean a page separating major parts of a book (generally each part would comprise several chapters).

Half-title verso: The page following the half-title. It often contains a list of other books by the same author.

}
```

I've noticed a similar problem with this `\vp` macro that I found here: https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/plain/contrib/misc/paragraphs.tex. I use it in heading macros to suppress the first paragraph indent after a heading.

```
\def\unindent {%
  \setbox0=\lastbox}     

\def\vp {%
  \everypar{\unindent\everypar{}}}

\vp

{\it First} paragraph. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

Second Paragraph. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.

Third Paragraph. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
```

Because the first word of the first paragraph is in a different font, both the first and the second paragraphs lose their indents. This macro also uses `\everypar` and `\setbox0=\lastbox`.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `\everypar` tokens are inserted when something triggers the start of a paragraph. In the case of `{\it First}` it is `F`. Hence `\hang` is issued in a group and the ending of the group nullifies its effect. Do

```
\leavevmode{\it First}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

egreg already described what is causing this, so there is an easy way to make your `\everypar` immune to this: Make the `\hang` `\global`:

```
\everypar{\global\hang\setbox0=\lastbox}
```

Comment: This consumes two cells of the save stack per call of `\everypar`, so it can make TeX to run out of memory. Well, on my current distribution this happens after 39979 paragraphs, but…